# purpose of Ingress as etc/hosts makes redirection to NodePort?

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, hosts-file, kubernetes-nodeport

I actually work on a projet to understand Ingress behaviour,
but i do not understand interest of using it,
as etc/hosts make the job.
Here is the exact workflow to understand my questioning

I have a Pod, exposed by a NodePort service, on port : 31001
the ip adress of one my nodes is : 192.168.49.2

So, when i launch this adress in a browser

```
http://192.168.49.2:31001/
```

i got my application with success.

Now i have an Ingress ressource with specification :

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: voting-domain
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - host: vote.votingapp.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: vote-ui
            port:
              number: 80
```

but i have to add a line in my /etc/hosts

```
192.168.49.2    vote.votingapp.com
```

Now, when i do

```
http://vote.votingapp.com:31001/
```

it is also a success. Ok, but not due to Ingress presence but
due to hosts file binding.
In fact, dur to hosts file

```
vote.votingapp.com --> 192.168.49.2 --> resolution is done
```

So, what is the interest of Ingress in my specific example ?

thanks by advance

Comment: Is this under your GKE resources? Just checking the tag in your post question.

Comment: Mostly ingress is host and path rules you can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress#multiple_backend_services) for this information.

Based on your setup, it was not directed to nodeport, it was directed to backendservice which is vote-ui using port 80.

Regarding the /etc/host I believe this is an OS configuration based on this [documentation](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-service-mesh/tutorials/kic/ingress-walkthrough/#:~:text=To%20access%20the%20Bookinfo%20application%3A)